# Apache CXF Password Type Always Sets Digest

Tags: apache, web-services, soap, cxf

I am working on a web service client project and using Apache CXF to send request to web service.
I need to set passwordType as PasswordText. But even if I set it in OutInterceptor property, It always sets passwordType as Digest. How can I solve this issue?

My Code is this:

```
        JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
        factory.setServiceClass(Test.class);
        factory.setAddress(url);
        factory.getInInterceptors().add(new SoapActionInInterceptor(action));
        factory.getOutInterceptors().add(new SoapActionOutInterceptor());
        Map<String, Object> outProps = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, WSHandlerConstants.USERNAME_TOKEN);
        outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.USER, username);
        outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PASSWORD_TYPE, WSConstants.PASSWORD_TEXT);

        ClientPasswordHandler handler = new ClientPasswordHandler();
        handler.setPassword(password);
        outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_REF, handler);

        WSS4JStaxOutInterceptor wssOut = new WSS4JStaxOutInterceptor(outProps);
        factory.getOutInterceptors().add(wssOut);
        T serviceClient = (T) factory.create();
        Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(serviceClient);

        setClientPolicy(client);
```

And clientPolicy is this

```
   protected synchronized void setClientPolicy(Client client) {
    if (client != null) {
        HTTPConduit httpConduit = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
        httpConduit.setAuthSupplier(null);
        httpConduit.setAuthorization(null);
        HTTPClientPolicy clientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
        clientPolicy.setConnectionTimeout(60000L);
        clientPolicy.setReceiveTimeout(60000L);
        httpConduit.setClient(clientPolicy);
    }
   }
```

> org.apache.cxf -> version 3.1.6
>
> org.apache.wss4j -> version 2.1.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. WSS4JStaxOutInterceptor extends AbstractWSS4JStaxInterceptor and it has a function to set incoming properties which we have send. When it try to set password property it checks incoming property with "PasswordText" string and when we use WSConstants its value is different. That's why when we set property value with "PasswordText" string it works fine. Final code for interceptor is:

```
private WSS4JStaxOutInterceptor createSecurityInterceptor() {
    Map<String, Object> outProps = new HashMap<>();
    outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, WSHandlerConstants.USERNAME_TOKEN);
    outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.USER, username);
    // AbstractWSS4JStaxInterceptor class parseNonBooleanProperties require "PasswordText" check this function before changing this line
    outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PASSWORD_TYPE, "PasswordText");
    // AbstractWSS4JStaxInterceptor class parseNonBooleanProperties require "PasswordText" check this function before changing this line

    ClientPasswordHandler handler = new ClientPasswordHandler();
    handler.setPassword(password);
    outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_REF, handler);
    return new WSS4JStaxOutInterceptor(outProps);
}
```

This solves the issue.